# Can I Install Ubuntu On My tablet ZTE V9C?

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.04

**Can I Install Ubuntu On My tablet ZTE V9C** It has 275 mb of phone storage and 512mb of ram

Answer (score 0):

Well first you have to make sure that your phone can handle Ubuntu. :-)

You can do this here: http://pdadb.net/

I looked it up for you and it's seems compatible.

Here is an instruction on how to do so: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1872752

Good Luck!